# "We even had an X each" or "each of us even had an X"?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-choice

Example:

> My friends and I were crazy about marbles in elementary school; we
>   even had a favorite one each.
>
> My friends and I were crazy about marbles in elementary school; each
>   of us even had a favorite one.

What's the correct (or most common) construction? And why?

Comment: _...we each had a favorite one, even_. I didn't downvote, but I can guess why this question might have attracted a downvote. What makes you think there's a "correct" or "most common" construction? We get too many questions like this one: two phrasings, A & B, asking which is the "correct" one. It's a proofreading request, really. Moreover, there are **many** correct ways to word this – _everyone had a favorite marble; every one of us had a personal favorite; no one was without a favorite; who didn't have a favorite?_ – with so many good choices, who cares which of your two is "most common?"

Comment: @J.R. : Methinks those are given out in some English courses or books, with the goal to introduce a more idiomatic use to the reader/student...  In this very example "a favorite one each" at the end of a sentence does ***not*** sound natural, at least to my ear.

Comment: @Victor - If these come from a book, the O.P. should say so. If they come from the O.P.'s head, that should be stated as well. This user has asked too many questions in this form, like [70511](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70511), [70416](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70416), [70025](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70025), [69579](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69579), [65404](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65404), [60969](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60969), etc. This kind of _A-vs-B_ question is getting all too common and stale.

Comment: Yes, I thought about the sentences myself. Since I didn't get downvotes before (and got upvotes instead), I thought the questions were okay.

Comment: You got upvotes on *some* of those questions. [Many](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/1806/alexchenco?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=5) have no votes at all, suggesting a lukewarm reception at best. I think many of your questions could be more interesting and useful if you spent a little bit more time telling us where you got the material from, and did a better job of figuring out the root issue, instead of just asking us to pick one of two choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of taste! both of the sentences you have written are right.